# Type erasing on a settable subscript gives strange error; is this a compiler bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: xcode, swift

Is the following a compiler bug or am I doing something wrong:

```
protocol Subscriptable {
    associatedtype Element
    associatedtype Index
    var firstIndex: Index { get }
    var lastIndex: Index { get }
    subscript(index: Index) -> Element { get set }
}

struct AnySubscriptable<E, I>: Subscriptable {
    typealias Element = E
    typealias Index = I
    let firstIndexee: () -> I
    let lastIndexee: () -> I
    let subscriptee: (index: I) -> E
    let setSubscriptee: (index: I, element: E) -> Void
    var firstIndex: I { return firstIndexee() }
    var lastIndex: I { return lastIndexee() }
    subscript(index: I) -> E {
        get { return subscriptee(index: index) }
        set { setSubscriptee(index: index, element: newValue) }
    }
}

extension Array {
    var asScriptable: AnySubscriptable<Element, Int> {
        return AnySubscriptable(
            firstIndexee: { return self.startIndex }, // Error: Cannot convert `() -> Int` to expected `() -> _`
            lastIndexee: { return self.endIndex },
            subscriptee: { return self[$0] },
            setSubscriptee: { self[$0] = $1 }
        )
    }
}
```

The error, "Cannot convert `() -> Int` to expected `() -> _`", on the `firstIndexee` closure in the extension is strange because:

1. The type is correct
2. There is no error on `lastIndexee`
3. If `set` is removed from `subscript` in `Subscriptable`, and hence `setSubscriptee` etc. in `AnySubscriptable` and in the extension, then the error goes away.

Compiler bug or my mistake?

Thanks in advance for any help,

-- Howard.

Comment: did you get this working? I am trying to get subscript and variables working with type erasure, see my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39593295/1311272

Comment: got it working thx to your solution, thx!

Comment: See answer added below

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading what is required is a mutable copy of `self` for the `setSubscriptee` capture of `self`:

```
extension Array {
    var asSubscriptable: AnySubscriptable<Element, Int> {
        var mutableSelf = self // Without this line type inference fails with a *very* misleading error message!
        return AnySubscriptable(
            firstIndexee: { return self.startIndex },
            lastIndexee: { return self.endIndex },
            subscriptee: { return self[$0] },
            setSubscriptee: { mutableSelf[$0] = $1 }
        )
    }
}
```